# Tkinter command problems using Toplevel on child class

Tags: python, tkinter, command

Trying to write a simple gui which has multiple child classes but the toplevel is not recognizing the attributes that I set with the command on a button so that it prints anything the user puts in the box. i have no clue why it isn't working on the child class

```
   from Tkinter import *
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkSimpleDialog
    import tkMessageBox

    class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

            self.button = tk.Button(self, text="mx lookup",command=self.create_window)
            self.button.pack(side="left")





        def create_window(self):

            l = tk.Toplevel(self)
            l.entry = tk.Entry(l)
            l.button = tk.Button(l, text="search mx", command l.enter)

            l.entry.pack()
            l.button.pack()
        def enter(l):
            dns =(l.entry.get())
                  print(dns)






    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = tk.Tk()
        main = MainWindow(root)
        main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `command l.enter` it should be `command = self.enter`

To pass the widget (Toplevel) `command = lambda: self.enter(l)` or pass `l.entry` and then you can just call `l.get()`

Also I think you want `dns = l.entry.get()` to print the entry widgets text

You should add self at the beginning of your enter function as an argument to call self.enter with an additional arguement, or you could just refactor this outside of your class.

Comment: it is still coming up with an error on line 22 says that it take exactly 1 argument but it was given 2 any solution

Answer (score 0):

You have many issues with your code:

1. You have a typo in `command l.enter`. Correct it: `command = self.enter`
2. The notations `l.entry` and `l.button`  are wrong because this means in Python that you have already created attributes called entry and button which you are now allowed to access with the dot notation as you did. You should rename  these to something else. For example: `l_entry` and `l_entry`.
3. Consequently to ***2.***, in `enter()` you will need to modify `l.entry.get()` to `l_entry.get()`
4. To be able to use `l_entry.get()` in enter() method, you will need to write `self.l_entry = tk.Button(self.l, text="search mx", command= self.enter)` in `create_window()` and then in `enter()` write `dns =(self.l_entry.get())` instead of `dns =(l_entry.get())`.

Your program becomes now like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import tkSimpleDialog
import tkMessageBox

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       self.button = tk.Button(self, text="mx lookup",command=self.create_window)
       self.button.pack(side="left")

   def create_window(self):
       self.l = tk.Toplevel(self)              
       self.l_entry = tk.Entry(self.l)
       self.l_button = tk.Button(self.l, text="search mx", command= self.enter)    
       self.l_entry.pack()
       self.l_button.pack()

   def enter(self):
       dns =(self.l_entry.get())
       print(dns)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = tk.Tk()
   main = MainWindow(root)
   main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
   root.mainloop()
```